# Love's equation $f(x)+\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{f(t)}{1+(x-t)^2}dt=1, \ \ (|x|\geq 1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Let us consider Love's equation:
$$f(x)+\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{f(t)}{1+(x-t)^2}dt=1, \ \ (|x|\geq 1)$$
Is $f(x)$ a two times differentiable function?